# C# Azure WebJob - use Publish Profile information in code

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I would like to keep a separate testing and production environment while using the same code for a WebJob. The two environments are published to different app services, and so if I can get the `SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish`, `MSDeployServiceURL`, `DeployIisAppPath`, or `UserName` property, I can use the value to determine which storage account to connect to, and the two storage accounts are set up to work the same way. Is it possible to get any of those properties at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to:

1. Remove the connection string from App.config and put it in the Azure App Service's Application settings (Connection strings section).
2. Add the connection string dynamically to JobHostConfiguration:

   ```
       var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
       string storageConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
       config.DashboardConnectionString = storageConnectionString;
       config.StorageConnectionString = storageConnectionString;
   ```

It may be possible to just add the connection strings without dynamically adding them to JobHostConfiguration, but I wanted to put in the connection string once and reuse it.